# Calculating pi with Python

Tags: python, pi

I tried to write a python script to calculate pi. I know there are hundreds out there that could do it for me but that defeats the purpose of learning, hence the question.

I found a way to calculate pi on the following site: https://nl.wikihow.com/Pi-berekenen it's the first from method 2. The site is in Dutch, I'm sorry. The way I want to do it is also explained in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrRMnzANHHs&t=8s (that is english).

I tried the following script:

```
from decimal import *
def fractions():
    fractions = input("How many fractons to add")
    return fractions

fractions = fractions()


def calculate(fractions):
    fractions = fractions
    i=0 
    x=1
    total = Decimal(0)  
    plus = True
    while i < fractions:
        if plus:
            total = Decimal(total) + Decimal(4/x)
            plus = False
        else:
            total = Decimal(total) - Decimal(4/x)   
            plus = True
        print Decimal(total)
        print x
        print plus
        i= i + 1
        x= x + 2
    return Decimal(total)


pi = calculate(fractions)
print pi
```

But it only outputs the following:
[Output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiFcD.png)

I don't know why it keeps hanging at 3, because if it rounds the numbers it should go to 2 atleast 1 time in this sequence.

So the question is, what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Because you're using python 2, whenever you divide an integer by a float it will round to the nearest integer.  For any divisor 3 or greater, 4/x rounds to 0.  Replace `4/x` in your code with `4.0/x`.

Comment: thanks! my code works now :) I'm glad I didn't make any big mistakes in the build up of the program :)